# Exploding animation using css3.

Tags: css

I'm new to this site and coding. I am trying to find out how to create an exploding image on hover using css or css3. Can anyone tell me if this is possible. Any comments would be great.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: To answer the question: yes it's possible. We'll need a lot more info from you however to answer the inevitable 'how' question you're going to ask next.

Comment: http://www.designzzz.com/coding/css3-explosion-effect-menu/      

http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

Answer (score 5):

If you want it to break up into multiple pieces when ‘exploding’, I don't think you can do that with just CSS3. If, on the other hand, you consider making it very large ‘exploding’, then that is very much doable:

```
img {
    transition: 0.5s;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(3) rotate(10deg);
}
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Xn7/embedded/result,html,css/)**　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　<sub>okay, I guess that's not much of an explosion, but oh well</sub>

Comment: This is a nice, quick "exploding" effect without having to resort to Javascript.

Comment: You can use different transition times for different options, e.g. using background, using width/height, scale, ... then you can break up into several pieces. Just use `transition XXX options, XXX options, ....`